# Removing delete permanently button in uploading files media

Tags: attachments, media-library, media-modal

How do I delete or remove the word *Delete Permanently* in uploading files?
I wanted to remove this permanently so that the users won't keep deleting files which are not supposed to delete.

[image: WordPress attachment details]

I use this code:

```
.button-link.delete-attachment{display:none}
```

But the problem of this, if the user uses the inspect element, they can just change it to `display:block` to show the delete button. Using CSS is not an option.

Is there a function code here to remove this? Or where can I find the core file in `wp-admin` folder, so that I could delete the `<div>` element manually?

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick!

css:

```
.media-sidebar .details .edit-attachment {
    display: none;
}
.media-sidebar .details .delete-attachment {
    display: none;
}
```

And this:

```
foreach( array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) as $hook )
    add_action( "admin_print_styles-$hook", 'admin_styles_so_25894288');

function admin_styles_so_25894288() {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'post' !== $typenow )
        return;
    ?>
    <style>
        .media-sidebar .details .delete-attachment
        { 
            display: block; 
        }
        .media-sidebar .details .edit-attachment
        { 
            display: block; 
        }
    </style>
    <?php

}
```

Comment: A removal via CSS is always still active and user with the knowledge can do that.